# tkinter Python 3 Menu Error - Nothing Loads?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import sys
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from sys import exit

class AppUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, relief=SUNKEN, bd=2)

        self.menubar = Menu(self)

        filemenu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=self.NewFile)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=self.OpenFile)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        menu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=menu)
        menu.add_command(label="Cut")
        menu.add_command(label="Copy")
        menu.add_command(label="Paste")

    def OpenFile():
        name = askopenfilename
        askopenfilename()

    def NewFile():
        tm.showerror("ERROR", "Cannot Open New File!")

        try:
            self.master.config(menu=self.menubar)
        except AttributeError:
            self.master.tk.call(master, "config", "-menu", self.menubar)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self, bg="white", width=400, height=400,
                             bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()


root = Tk()

app = AppUI(root)
app.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I can't seem to work this .py file, I am new-ish to coding with python, I have asked and looked about, but I can't seem to find the answer. I have tried to make a class with a menu in it, but the error seems to always say "self is not defined"

Thanks

Comment: please don't put your code on pastebin and link to it. If you aren't willing to invest the tiny bit of time it takes to make a proper post, why should we be willing to take the time to answer it? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE)

Comment: I don't know how to post it like everyone else does? sorry.

Comment: Then learn. Stackoverflow has tons of help available. Simply paste your code into the question, highlight the code, and click the button that looks like `{}`.

Comment: Alright. done, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see nothing because your frame has a default size of 0x0 since there is nothing inside.

```
Frame.__init__(self, master, relief=SUNKEN, bd=2, width=200, height=200)
```

should make it visible. Furthermore, I advise you to make your `AppUI` class inherit from `Tk` or `Toplevel` instead of `Frame` so that you can directly use `self.configure(menu=self.menubar)` to display the menu.

Also, `def OpenFile():` should be replaced by `def OpenFile(self):` otherwise you will get the error `TypeError: OpenFile() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` when you call `self.OpenFile()` (and the same is true for `NewFile`).